# MySQL Query is taking a very long time

Tags: mysql, sql, database, optimization

I have a query that takes a list of stations around a given location, and from another table searches for an ID for a row that has the same coordinates as the stations queried, and concatenates all 'Line' columns that have the same ID as the one queried from the second table.

The query looks like this

```
SELECT Instance,
Namespace, 
Stations.Name, 
Stations.Lat, 
Stations.Lon, 
Temp, 
Humid, 
(SELECT ID FROM transportData.stations WHERE stations.Lat = Stations.Lat AND stations.Lon = Stations.Lon) AS 'StationID',
( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(44.436292) ) * cos( radians( Stations.Lat ) ) * cos( radians( Stations.Lon ) - radians(26.102452) ) + sin( radians(44.436292) ) * sin(radians(Stations.Lat)) ) ) AS distance,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Line SEPARATOR ';') FROM transportData.timeTables WHERE timeTables.Station = StationID GROUP BY timeTables.Station) AS 'Lines'
FROM `Stations`
WHERE `Namespace` LIKE "%8" 
HAVING distance < 0.1
ORDER BY distance
```

however, this query, that would return only one station (within a radius of 100 m of the provided coordinates) took 58 seconds to execute.

Any advice on how to optimize this?

EDIT:
The Stations table:

```
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Instance  | varchar(6)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Namespace | varchar(10)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Name      | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Lat       | decimal(9,6)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Lon       | decimal(9,6)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Temp      | float         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Humid     | float         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Bio       | varchar(3000) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Photo     | varchar(1000) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Phone     | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Website   | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| OpenHours | varchar(1024) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The transportData.stations table:

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Name  | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Lat   | varchar(15) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Lon   | varchar(15) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Type  | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The timeTables table:

```
+----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID       | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Line     | varchar(10)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Station  | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Weekdays | varchar(3500) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Weekends | varchar(3500) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

EDIT: I tried using some MariaDB spatial functions, and found this to work ST_Distance(point(44.436292,26.102452), point(Lat, Lon)), but it gives me weird readings that are not similar with the ones from the formula I previously had. This is probably because ST_Distance returns the distance on a plane, which is useless, because it does not take into consideration the curvature of earth.

Comment: please show your table structures and your index structures.

Comment: That query is doing an awful lot of computation, and as you're operating on a computed column, it's going to require a table scan. Those are necessarily slower than an indexed version. If you're doing a lot of GIS work, use the [MySQL Spatial Extensions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html).

Comment: can you filter the stations based on values somehow...if its 0.1 km away...then the longitude and latitude of the stations you want to find should be close to your input...that should significantly limit your computations

Comment: @Martin I have added the table structure.

Comment: Ok, if you're working with GPS data, two choice : 1) you have a small data set and know most of the output so you can make up something; or 2) you really work with spacial data, and you go with spacial column and spacial index (we speak about a change of 50s to <10ms query, if you need to argument this with you boss)

Answer (score 0):

With what you give, this is the best answer I can provide:

/!\ I can't test it, so I hope it work as you want.

I put an index to speed up a bit the WHERE, and assume you'll search for `< 0.1km`.

```
CREATE INDEX small_miracle 
    ON `Stations`(`Namespace`, `Lat`, `Lon`);

SELECT 
    Instance,
    Namespace, 
    Stations.Name, 
    Stations.Lat, 
    Stations.Lon, 
    Temp, 
    Humid, 
    TDS.ID AS 'StationID',
    ( 
        6371 
        * acos( 
              cos( radians(44.436292) ) 
            * cos( radians( Stations.Lat ) ) 
            * cos( 
                radians( Stations.Lon ) 
                - radians(26.102452) 
                ) 
            + sin( radians(44.436292) ) 
            * sin(radians(Stations.Lat))
            ) 
        ) AS distance,
    timeTables.Lines AS 'Lines'
FROM `Stations`
INNER JOIN transportData.stations TDS
    ON (
        TDS.Lat = Stations.Lat
        AND TDS.Lon = Stations.Lon
        )
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        timeTables.Station,
        GROUP_CONCAT(Line SEPARATOR ';') Lines
    FROM transportData.timeTables 
    GROUP BY timeTables.Station
) timeTables
    ON timeTables.Station = TDS.ID 
WHERE 
    `Namespace` LIKE "%8" 
    AND 26.102452 +0.1 > Stations.Lat
    AND 26.102452 -0.1 < Stations.Lat
    AND 44.436292 +0.1 > Stations.Lon
    AND 44.436292 -0.1 < Stations.Lon
    AND distance < 0.1
ORDER BY distance;
```

Comment: I tried using some MariaDB spatial functions, and found this to work
`ST_Distance(point(44.436292,26.102452), point(Lat, Lon))`, but it gives me weird readings that are not similar with the ones from the formula i had. PS: your query doesn't work, haven't figured it out why

Comment: @GeorgeLazu edit your  question with your try of `ST_Distance`. Do my query throw an error ? could you provide the create table and a data-sample to make some test ? (like 5 to 10 lines)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/SyYw6VGe
here's the table structure with a few rows

Comment: @GeorgeLazu I can't make your query work with this data sample http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef0d2d/12 is that normal ?

Comment: It's because the part of the query that gets a dataset as 'StationID' is commented. It doesn't matter anymore, I have changed my approach in such a way that I would query small bits of information when I needed them, instead of using that big query for every info I need at once.

Comment: @GeorgeLazu could you provide a working example with your query on  sqlfiddle.com ? I'll then be able to try a few thing ;)